# Нужно сделать с использованием lambda, но без функции def

Tags: python, lambda

И так, это сам условие задачи:описать процедуру InvertDigits(K), меняющую порядок следования цифр целого положительного числа K на обратный (K — параметр целого типа, являющийся одновременно входным и выходным). С помощью этой процедуры поменять порядок следования цифр на обратный для каждого из пяти данных целых чисел.

1. Как написать эту программу  с использованием lambda, но без функции def.
2. Как проще написать программу? Это мой код, да он не работает.Очень буду Вам благодарен за вашу помощь.

```
a=lambda (k):
s=str(k['k'])
s_new=s[::-1]
k['k']=int(s_new)

r={'k':None}
for i in range(5):
  print('число', i+1,':',r['k'])
  print('измененное=',r['k'])
  print()
```

Comment: Что ж последние дни этот [решебник](https://coolcode.ru/reshaem-zadachi-abramyan-na-phyton-3-proc7/) все насилуют? Хотя, по стилю написания вопросов похоже, что это один и тот же человек под разными никами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А может имелось в виду что-то такое:

```
numbers = [2131, 324234, 455466, 75675, 8977897895]
f = lambda x: str(x)[::-1]

for num in numbers:
    print(f(num))
```

Comment: Думаю что да. Я как обычно "ТЗ" не дочитал )))

Answer (score 2):

#### Если правильно понял задачу, то можно вот так попробовать

```py
a = '123456'
a = a[::-1]
print(a)
```

```py
a = '123456'
b, = map(lambda x: ''.join(reversed(x)), [a])
print(b)
# 654321
```

#### Можно еще вот так:

```py
a = '123456'
a = ''.join([let for num, let in sorted(enumerate(a), reverse=True)])
print(a)
```

#### Но если очень нужно приколхозить лямбду

```py
a = '123456'
a = ''.join([let for num, let in sorted(enumerate(a), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[0])])
print(a)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам, и за Вашу понимание.

Comment: @Gregory2124, Не за что